# RMarkdown: Space in LaTeX output at place of code for float

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown

When including code for a figure between two paragraphs in RMarkdown, the float resulting from the code might be placed at a different place of the document, leaving space between the paragraphs in the LaTeX/PDF output file.

The following minimal example illustrates the issue:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

This is my first paragraph. 
Next in the Rmd file would be the code for the figure.  
The figure is correctly treated as a float by LaTeX, meaning that LaTeX will put it to the next suitable position.
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Example", out.width='0.5\\textwidth', fig.pos='B'}
  plot(pressure)
```
The problem now is, that this leaves space to my second paragraph.
Usually, this should not be the case.
In pure LaTeX, there is a linebreak, of course, but no vertical space in addition.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `\vspace{-\parsep}` at the start of the following text, you'll get the line break without the extra space.  That is,

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

This is my first paragraph. 
Next in the Rmd file would be the code for the figure. 
The figure is correctly treated as a float by LaTeX, meaning that LaTeX will put it to the next suitable position.
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Example", out.width='0.5\\textwidth', fig.pos='B'}
  plot(pressure)
```
\vspace{-\parsep}The problem is now fixed.
````

I don't see any other way to do this:  `knitr` puts blank lines around the figure environment when it generates the LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is a nice workaround, although an option inside `knitr` to prevent the spaces around the environment would be nice.